# Can I express in SQL that an aggregation has only a single value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

Suppose I have a query like this:

```sql
select *
from (values
--   A   B   C
    (1, 11, 92),
    (1, 11, 117),
    (2, 11, 97),
    (3, 22, 65)
) x(a,b,c)
```

And then assume that we know that for each value in column `A` the value of column `B` is guaranteed to be the same. So it is impossible that the rows `(5, 6, 7)` and `(5, 7, 7)` both exist in the source data because in the example there are two different Values for `B` (6,7) which both reference `A=5`.

Now I would like to do some Aggregation like this on the data:

```sql
select a, b, max(c)
from (values
    (1, 11, 92),
    (1, 11, 117),
    (2, 11, 97),
    (3, 22, 65)
) x(a,b,c)
group by a
```

This will of course generate the error:

> ERROR:  column "x.b" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

As a workaround I can of course just write

```sql
select a, max(b), max(c) ...
```

Or I could add column `b` to the `group by`-clause. Both will work just fine. However it has two drawbacks:

1. It is confusing to read. When reviewing such a query I automatically wonder either why I am selecting only the max-Value for `b` or I wonder why I am grouping by this value. I need to extensively make sure that the assumption that the added `max` call or the added column in the `group by` clause is actually "do nothing" in a code review.
2. In case I am mistaken with that assumption this could cause severe bugs which are very hard to detect.

Is there a more expressive way to write that there will be only a single possible value in this group? E.g. an aggregation function that returns a single value, but throws an error if multiple values are present.

(In case you are wondering about the use case: I need to import some very large CSV files which are formatted like this. In the first step I create a temporary table and just load all values into that table. Then in the second step I do some aggregation and insertion queries directly from the temp table. The CSV files I need to import do have these characteristics that I am assuming.)

Comment: The `b` column is a foreign key to the `a` column. So you build the parent table first and then create the relationship. But I will post an answer not design related.

Comment: I am failing to understand why not just add b to the group by?  This is the intended design for aggregation when you want more than 1 column.  Are you worried that not all parts of your data adhere to the standard you are saying?

Comment: @Matt: Yes, I am worried that there may be data that does not adhere to the standard (or that I misunderstood the documentation for that matter) and instead of an error I will get wrong data which I will eventually notice after the data caused a huge mess.

Comment: Identifying that data prior to import would be possible and typically would be done first so that you can eliminate it or choose what to do.  The problem I see it is if you group by you might duplicate which might be problematic if you have a certain constraint.  But automatically choosing max or min b is selecting a valid row.  Will it always be the greater B is more valid? Typically if you got room I would move it to a staging table then to the final table but I understand that reluctance is very very large.

Answer (score 1):

[`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
select distinct on (a) *
from t
order by a, c desc
```

Comment: This is missing the grouping. How would I now get my `max(c)`?

Comment: @yankee The `order by` clause will make it return the row with the biggest `c`

Comment: Mhh Ok... But `max(c)` was only an example... Oftentimes I need `sum(c)`, then it will not work anymore, does it?

Comment: @yankee No. That's why a design solution is always better than hackery

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do to make sure your results are valid,
but you'll have to check in a couple of different ways.

Let's start with a query that produces *correct* rows, those meeting your assumptions.

```
with T (a, b, c) as (
select * from
   ( values
    (1, 11, 92),
    (1, 11, 117),
    (2, 11, 97),
    (3, 22, 65) ) x(a,b,c)
) 
select count(*) as N, A.a, min(B.b) as b, A.c
from (select a, max(c) as c from T group by a) as A
join (select distinct a, b from T) as B
on A.a = B.a
group by A.a, A.c
having count(*) = 1
```

(That's roughly right.  I didn't run it, and your DBMS may have slightly different CTE syntax.)

That gets you the max(c) for rows for which a:b have 1:1 cardinality.  To look for rows that *don't* meet that test -- an error -- run the same query with `count != 1`.  Or remove the `HAVING`, and test **N** in your program:

```
select count(*) as N, a, min(b) as b, max(c) as c
from ( values
    (1, 11, 92),
    (1, 11, 117),
    (2, 11, 97),
    (3, 22, 65) ) x(a,b,c)
group by a
```

If you are fairly certain about the a:b cardinality, declare a `UNIQUE` constraint in your table, and thereby ensure `min(b) === b`.

> It is confusing to read

Perhaps.  Someplace you have to say, *a:b should be 1:1, and here is where we reject rows that don't meet that test*.